# Internet Explorer 8 x64 on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have windows 7 x64 with 32-bit IE 8 installed. I want to upgrade to x64 edition of IE, but can't find it. There are only links to [IE 8 x64 for Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3AEDA9DB-B318-408A-860B-BC37BD6AB70C&displaylang=fi&displaylang=en)  but I get an error when try to install it, informing that platform is not supported

Please, advice where can I download IE 8 x64 for Windows 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll already have it installed.  Type 'internet explorer' into the Start Menu search box and you should see it.

Why do you want to use it, anyway?  It's not as though you need to use web apps that use 4GB+ of memory.  Any IE add-ons that you may want to use would be unlikely to be available for 64-bit and the Flash Player beta is also very buggy.

Comment: I too think so. When I installed Win 7 x64, there had been installed both versions of IE 8.

Comment: Wow... Flash for x64?  You're kidding right?  I mean x64 is SOOOOO new... it's only been around about 7 years... I'm surprised Adobe has a beta so quickly after its release! (I agree - stick with the 32bit version of IE... way too many plug-ins don't work with x64).

Comment: Thanks, i have it. I thought that i have only one version. Thank's a lot!